# Kernel get clear while printing the string with escaping 'mr \x0c'

Tags: python, escaping

While running the code `a = 'Mr. stack\n\x0c'`  `print(a)` my kernel is getting clear what does it mean.
But if I slice the string like `print(a[:-1])` It was working fine. What does the escaping mean?

If any details required make a comment I will provide. Thank you

Comment: Sorry it's about python kernel

Comment: ``\x0c`` is a **form feed**. You could read about that character in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58421027/what-is-the-use-for-control-characters-in-string-printable. If by "my kernel is getting clear" you mean that a console seems to show nothing, then it could be the very effect of form feed: it scrolls the output by one page.